# Comparing 2 wchar_t arrays

Tags: c++, string, wchar-t

I'm sure this is sooo simple but I've come from a c# background where strings are easy and now I am making a small trip into the unmanaged world I am very confused.

Essentially I am using EnumDisplayDevices to list the available devices, I want to target a particular adapter so I need to compare DeviceString and DeviceName against some know values to see whether or not I have the right adapter to work on.

But I am stumped, I defined the known value as such...

```
wchar_t devName[] = L"Intel(R) HD Graphics Family";
```

but direct comparison doesn't work - `if(devName == theDisplay.DeviceName)`

`strcmp` doesnt seem to work with wide chars so I have no idea what to do, anyone know how to do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `std::wstring`, it has an `operator==`.

Comment: This worked for me by using 2 std::wstrings thusly: if (devName.compare(dn) == 0)

Comment: @john: You should just use `if (devName == dn)`

Comment: I'm not sure whether to laugh or to cry, when the OP says that "in C# strings are simple", and then you have to write all this member function nonsense for a simple comparison. As far as I can tell, C++ is one of the few C-like languages where you can compare strings like a sane person with `s1 == s2`.

Comment: to what member function nonsense do you refer? Typically in c# if I want to compare 2 string I make 2 strings and use strcmp, simple. As I said in my original post s1 == s2 did not work with wchar_t arrays.

Comment: @johnbowring: It's a `std::wstring`. As I said earlier. You can just compare a pair of `std::wstring` by using `if (s1 == s2)`, where `s1` and `s2` are `std::wstring`. You're confused because you're so busy trying to make C++ look like C#, you haven't learned a scrap about C++. C++ 101: Use the Standard string classes for all string handling needs.

Answer (score 13):

If you check Visual Studio help for `strcmp`, you'll find it lists 3 functions to compare strings: `strcmp`, `wcscmp` and `_mbscmp`. The one you're looking for is `wcscmp`.